# Deutoronomy 22:23,25 LXX translation

Tags: hebrew, septuagint, torah

In Brenton Septuagint, the translation of the same word in hebrew - מאורשה, is different between verse 23 and verse 25:

> “And if there be a young damsel **espoused** to a man...” (Deuteronomy 22:23, Brenton)

> “But if a man find in the field a damsel that is **betrothed**...” (Deuteronomy 22:25, Brenton)

But the word in hebrew מאורשה is the same in both verses.

Why the translation differs?

Comment: The 'betrothed' references only the woman, not the man, therefore the overall betrothed state is the correct translation. The 'espoused' references the espousal of said woman to an individual man, thus the act of espousal (one to the other) is also the more accurate translation in regard to how English differentiates the state and the act. Up-voted +1.

Comment: @NigelJ I think this is the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the OP states in comment that their opinion is that 'this is the answer' I am making it an answer rather than just a comment.

---

The 'betrothed' references only the woman, not the man, therefore the overall betrothed state is the correct translation.

The 'espoused' references the espousal of said woman to an individual man, thus the act of espousal (one to the other) is also the more accurate translation in regard to how English differentiates the state and the act.

Answer (score 0):

The Brenton Septuagint was published in 1870 and uses a slightly archaic meaning for "espoused."

> [**Espoused**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/espoused)
> 3. *Archaic.* engaged or betrothed:
> *Espoused couples desiring to be married by the Ministerial Staff are required to complete the six-week preparation course.*

So the two words can mean the same thing. Also, in ancient Judaism, a [betrothal](https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/5843-erusin) constituted a legal marriage and required a certificate of divorce to dissolve. So in translating Deuteronomy here, *espoused* and *betrothed* are both appropriate choices.